# Ubuntu Forgets Samsung G9

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, samsung

One of my displays is a [Samsung G9](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/gaming/49-odyssey-g9-gaming-monitor-lc49g97tssnxdc/), and every time I lock the machine and the displays go blank, Ubuntu has "forgotten" about the G9 when I log back in. It works fine on the next restart, and it will sporadically recognize the display again if I unplug and plug the DisplayPort cable back in.

By "forgotten" I mean the monitor is not shown under display settings, and while it is visible in the Nvidia control panel X server settings, it is stuck on "Disabled".

I've been able to replicate this behavior with the same set of displays connected to two different Ubuntu machines. One is a laptop running 20.04.03 and connected with DisplayPort-to-USBC adapters. The other is a desktop running 22.04 with all displays plug directly into the GPU card.